# Validation fails on contribution with profile included

Tags: profile, contributions, confirmation, validation

Using 4.7.24 with php 5.6.

I have a contribution form set up with Confirmation page turned on, and a profile is included to collect extra address information (besides a billing address).  Several of the fields on the profile are marked as required.

When I try to test the form, validation fails when I try to complete the transaction on the confirmation page.  This seems strange to me since validation should have taken place on the Contribution page already (only?).  I have confirmed that if I remove the profile or turn off the confirmation page, everything works great.

I have run this through a debugger and at the validate function, it looks for data to validate in ->submitValues.  But submitted values aren't there, except for qfKey, entryURL and _qf_default.  This seems to be OK since it's the same situation when profiles aren't included, and the form processes successfully.

So if ->submitValues doesn't contain data by this stage, why is validation looking there? Should validation even happen on the Confirmation page? And if so, why is it failing for my form when all the required fields are actually filled out?

Comment: Can you clarify a bit : what is the exact error you have ? Do you have screenshots ?

Comment: Sure.  It's the standard "required field" validation error on about 7 fields.
 Please correct the following errors in the form fields below:

    First Name is a required field.
    Last Name is a required field.
    Street Address (Shipping) is a required field.
    City (Shipping) is a required field.
    Country (Shipping) is a required field.
    Postal Code (Shipping) is a required field.
    Phone (Shipping) is a required field.